# download task is not timed out after timeout value

Tags: ansible

Playbook:

```
- name: "download file"                       
  uri:                                        
    url: https://download.sonatype.com/nexus/3/latest-unix.tar.gz    
    method: GET                                                   
    dest: /tmp/nexus-unix.tar.gz           
    return_content: yes
  register: nexus_download
  until: nexus_download.status == 200
  retries: 24
  delay: 5
  
- name: extract nexus 
  command: tar -xvf /tmp/nexus-unix.tar.gz -C /home/bindu
  when: nexus_download.changed
  sudo: true

- name: move the nexus directory
  command: chdir=/home/bindu mv nexus-* nexus
  when: nexus_download.changed

- name: start nexus service
  shell: chdir="/home/bindu/neuxs/bin" ./nexus start
  when: nexus_download.changed
```

I have tried downloading nexus.tar.gz manually and is taking 10m time.

**Expected Result:** `download file` task should get timedout after 2min (24*5=120sec) and followed tasks should be skipped.

**Actual Result:** playbook execution hanged at `download file` task after 1 hour also.

Comment: I guess the problem is your internet I executed your first task and it was executed in 108 seconds. Maybe when ansible is trying to download the file there is a problem and it try again to download the file. You set `retries` 24 times, try with less. Have you tried with `command` module?

Comment: @garylopez if download completes within 120 seconds then will continues next tasks wihout any issues. but if dowlod didn't complete in 2min, it suppose to timeout and next tasks should be skipped. not sure why it's not happening.

Comment: `delay` is the amount of time between the reties. You did not set a timeout, and the default is of the timeout is 30s ([see documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/uri_module.html#parameter-timeout)). So that's a first reason for the math you're doing not summing up properly.

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε if I understood correctly `nexus_download.status` == 200 checked after 5sec for 24 times.  if file dowloaded before 2min, let's say at 15th time then will go to next task. but if not donwload didn't completes within 2min what will happen? if `download file` task needs to wait for 15m with keep on checking `nexus_download.status` what needs to be changed?

Comment: You did not understand correctly. Download status will be checked when the download task stops, either because it succeeded, errored or timed out. If the status check fails, then wait for 5 seconds and retry 24 times max. If your download is just tremendously slow, you won't get any retry and have to wait for it to complete. Setting a timeout won't help in that case as this will end the download only if no data goes over the wire for that period. My 2 cent: copy the file automatically each night on a cache on your network and use it from there.